# How to pass a command line argument to sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, sidekiq

To set up the delayed paperclip gem it provides the following instructions:

"Make sure that Sidekiq is ... listening to the paperclip queue, either by adding it to your sidekiq.yml config file under - queues: or by passing the command line argument -q paperclip to Sidekiq."

How would I do this?

Comment: The title is too vague, and it isn't obvious from the question, what you're trying to accomplish. Neither paperclip nor Sidekiq have this in their basic installation instructions on github.

Comment: The delayed paperclip gem has these instructions.

Comment: Well, if the sidekiq wiki is any guide, it's clear they're talking about a shell command line. E.g.: ```sidekiq -q whatever``` to start a sidekiq process with specific options.  So, a shell script?

Comment: Yes. How do I do that? I've added "worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e production -q paperclip" to my procfile.

Comment: Ah. Off the top of my head, something like this comes to mind: ```bundle exec sidekiq start -e production -q paperclip``` but I could be wrong. Sorry for all the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/pzaich/6157498/raw/14e03c36c8e64271f3090d0e6292404b92470762/sidekiq_delayed_paperclip.rb) that uses the YAML option.

```
#/config/sidekiq.yml
:concurrency: 7
:queues:
  - [high, 7]
  - [default, 5]
  - [paperclip, 5]
```